# Being morse function for a determinant map on M(n)

Tags: differential-topology

Show that the determinant map on M(n) is Morse function if n=2.

I know that f  to be a morse function, all critical points for f must be nondegenerate.

But i dont know how i calculate the derivative of a determinant map

Answer (score 1):

Well, you do have $n=2$, after all. So write the matrix as $\begin{bmatrix} x&y\\z&w\end{bmatrix}$, and then you have no problem differentiating the determinant function. :)

Comment: What about n> 2 ?

Comment: I want to learn the general derivative of a determinant map for arbitrary n

Comment: Use the cofactor expansion of the determinant in general to compute the derivative with respect to $x_{ij}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the diffeomorphism $M_n(\mathbb{R}) \stackrel{\sim}{=} \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.